# accordion menu trigger by toggle

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a 2 level Acccordion menu that I want to hide in the mobile view, and add a menu text so that when click on it, it opens up the 1st level first, and the 2nd level opens if the parent is clicked, but I don't quite know how to make it happens correctly.

Here is my demo code. Right now when click on the Menu it opens up all levels of Acccordion.

http://jsbin.com/upuwiy/3/edit

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to have the 2nd-level options initially hidden

You can see an example here, i added inner-options class on each inner ul , which sets the display property to none.

[fixed version](http://jsbin.com/upuwiy/4/edit)

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with this part of your code.  This only hides the main ul not the inner ul's.

```
jQuery('ul.sf-menu').hide();//hide all nested ul's
```

try this

```
jQuery('ul.sf-menu ul').hide();//hide all nested ul's
```

Comment: yeah, I was just trying to show you your selector was off.  If you want to use only jquery you can call $('ul').hide();. That will hide all ul's. But the css in the other answer works fine.